# add a time offset to a date object and passing it as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an assignment in which i have to display 10 analog clocks, only with a second hand. every clock shows the time one second forward in comparing to the one above. they should all be in the same component.

i was thinking about using the delay as a prop for each component and wrapping them with another component.

this is the code i wrote so far:

```
 interface IProps {
    offset: {
        offsetValue: number 
    }
}
 
const Clock = (props: IProps) => {
    
    
    
const [time,setTime] = useState(new Date())

useEffect(() => {
    
    const interval = setInterval( () => setTime(new Date))
    //props.offset
})
    
    
    let sec = time.getSeconds()
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Clock
```

I'm completely lost

Comment: your intreval missing the time that will triger the interval
did you try something like this?
const interval = setInterval( () => setTime(new Date),2000)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this offset number to the `Date` displayed, as seconds.

```
const Clock = (props: IProps) => {
    const { offset: { offsetValue } } = props;
    const interval = useRef<number|null>(null);
    const [time, setTime] = useState<Date|null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        interval.current = setInterval(() => {
            const now = new Date();
            const withOffset = new Date(now.getTime() + offsetValue*1000);
            setTime(withOffset);
        }, 1000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <span>{time}</span>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm using typescript so yes.. it should work in theory beside the fact i need to make it all typesafe.

i have some ts related errors

```
const withOffset: Date
Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'Date' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.ts(2345)
No quick fixes available```

```
(property) React.MutableRefObject<undefined>.current: undefined
Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: @ItayHaim it should be type safe now..

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your state with a date that includes the offset from props. Also, be sure to return a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) from your effect hook callback so that the interval stops when the component unmounts. Otherwise, it'll create a leak where the interval timer keeps going after your component no longer exists (and try to update the state which no longer exists, etc.). I've provided a commented example below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-rDX1qhCdOdhLx+JQyh87GriSSmeJYO0-L5JFBujhiqV9jRCARgCE-GlEiUWFA4ABJGwwCDtLoYKDADBNJi4jXc+C9-YDpCCxoD9j7BtFz6q9Uk87BciqZYdW7elO+hJzkmBuKCxPJiNpn0ZlDZg-nZ+SMpID8kqQaD+SwrAhK0LhQOEJE9RJay3Ho4DoD1mRzcsvEua44HIJgMFpMBZAmKYZjkBREL4AR4FSCAIGRDYbyPHD+27OA4PrBCl37LhfBCFiYCIIcQVHW0QRHTE4GidI-BaCAsiwhRICiXIJhAGT2ECA8MKgPxiz3bCyCgDc623DiV3-YJXngQxJ0oHA2iicgUAIAgJxaGgmiweAUAKVJsEMYBOh7UcMCQVdv0CmC4kgthUEmNocGAQxWRoIMwsjbNcU07SbwAHgIMBcJVZAEieRMRAEdYCA+KRsvcPKCtxbM2S0IA)

```ts
import {default as React, ReactElement, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const SECOND = 1000; // 1s in ms

// get a new date from the current unix time (in ms), offset by a value (in seconds)
function getOffsetDate (seconds: number): Date {
  return new Date(Date.now() + (SECOND * seconds));
}

type ClockProps = {
  offset: {
    offsetValue: number; // seconds
  };
};
 
const Clock = (props: ClockProps): ReactElement => {
  const {offset: {offsetValue}} = props;
  // initialize state with the offset date
  const [date, setDate] = useState(getOffsetDate(offsetValue));

  useEffect(() => {
    // start an interval timeer, assign the timer ID to a variable
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      // create a new offset date
      const d = getOffsetDate(offsetValue);
      setDate(d);
    }, SECOND); // repeat the interval each second

    // return cleanup function from effect hook:
    // clear the interval timer using its ID so it stops when your component unmounts
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  // not strictly necessary, but exhaustive to add setDate to the dependency list
  }, [setDate]);

  return (
    <span>{date.getSeconds()}</span>
  );
};
```

You can see it working here:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.6/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const SECOND = 1000; // 1s in ms

// get a new date from the current unix time (in ms), offset by a value (in seconds)
function getOffsetDate (seconds: number): Date {
  return new Date(Date.now() + (SECOND * seconds));
}

type ClockProps = {
  offset: {
    offsetValue: number; // seconds
  };
};
 
const Clock = (props: ClockProps): ReactElement => {
  const {offset: {offsetValue}} = props;
  // initialize state with the offset date
  const [date, setDate] = useState(getOffsetDate(offsetValue));

  useEffect(() => {
    // start an interval timeer, assign the timer ID to a variable
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      // create a new offset date
      const d = getOffsetDate(offsetValue);
      setDate(d);
    }, SECOND); // repeat the interval each second

    // return cleanup function from effect hook:
    // clear the interval timer using its ID so it stops when your component unmounts
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  // not strictly necessary, but exhaustive to add setDate to the dependency list
  }, [setDate]);

  return (
    <span>{date.getSeconds()}</span>
  );
};

function Example () {
  const [offsets, setOffsets] = useState([...new Array(5).keys()]);
  return (
    <div>
      {
        offsets.map(seconds => (
          <div key={seconds}>
            {seconds < 0 ? '-' : '+'}{Math.abs(seconds)}: <Clock offset={{offsetValue: seconds}} />
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: You're going to have fun with the DOM and CSS to make the analog clock with a second hand!